# Generate two-column text from a text file

Tags: multicol

Is it possible to generate a document with two-column text by feeding as input a text file that contains just one column of words? For e.g I would like to typeset the contents of `/usr/share/dict/words` into a document with each page containing two columns. I am looking for an automated way to achieve this rather than hand-picking words and manually inserting them in the `twocolumn` environment.

EDIT 1:

Adding more details to make the question clear. If the input text file is like this:

```
babery
babeship
Babesia
babesiasis
Babhan
Babi
Babiana
babiche
babied
Babiism
...
...
```

I am looking for latex code that will generate a two-column output while placing exactly one word per row and do this across multiple pages.

For e.g on page1, fill as much text as possible in this format:

```
babery                       babillard
babeship                     Babine
Babesia                      babingtonite
babesiasis                   babirusa
Babhan                       babish
Babi                         babished
Babiana                      babishly
babiche                      babishness
babied                       Babism
Babiism                      Babist
babillard                    Babite
Babine                       bablah
babingtonite                 babloh
babirusa                     baboen
babish                       Babongo
babished                     baboo
babishly                     baboodom
babishness
Babism
```

and continue doing this on the subsequent pages.

Comment: your question isn't very clear, is `\documenclass[twocolumn]{article}\begin{document}\input{/usr/share/dict/words}\end{document}` an answer?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `\obeylines` directive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply `\input` the file, after setting up twocolumn and obeylines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
\input{words}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution!